# Config default image not saved (On first save, when no new image uploaded)

Tags: module, admin, magento-1, configuration

I have a module with some config options that are used in the admin configuration section, and these have defaults applied.

When the user has never pressed save in that section, all the defaults are read correctly. When they click save for the first time, magento correctly stores all the defaults in the database (assuming they haven't changed anything), however any default images are instead set to 'null', wiping them from the config as if they'd never been set.

This only happens on the first ever save, and only if they haven't assigned a new image to that config value.

Is there a way to have magento store the default image path provided at all?

Comment: what code are you using for this? how does the default watermarks upload work in this case?